# How to dynamically convert dataframe columns to map

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, dynamic, multiple-columns

How to convert the data to map in PySpark, for dynamic columns?

**Input dataframe:**

| key_column | Column_1 | Column_2 | ..... | Column_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value_1 | Value_2 | ..... | Value_N |
| 1 | Value_a | Value_2 | ...... | Value_Z |
| 2 | Value_1 | Value_2 | ..... | Value_N |

**Expected output dataframe**:

| key_column | Map_output |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Column_1":"Value_1, Value_a", "Column_2":"Value_2", ......, "Column_N":"Value_N, Value_Z"} |
| 2 | {"Column_1":"Value_1", "Column_2":"Value_2", ......, "Column_N":"Value_N"} |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `create_map` function with `reduce()`.

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']  # can use sdf.columns for all columns in dataframe

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('val01', 'val02', 'val03'), ('val11', 'val12', 'val13')]). \
    toDF(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']). \
    withColumn('allcol_map', 
               func.create_map(*reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [[func.lit(k), func.col(k)] for k in col_list]))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------+
# |col1 |col2 |col3 |allcol_map                                   |
# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------+
# |val01|val02|val03|{col1 -> val01, col2 -> val02, col3 -> val03}|
# |val11|val12|val13|{col1 -> val11, col2 -> val12, col3 -> val13}|
# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- allcol_map: map (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- key: string
#  |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

---

We can also use `map_from_entries` function that requires an array of structs. The struct fields will be converted into the maps. It will output the same result as aforementioned.

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']  # can use sdf.columns for all columns in dataframe

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('val01', 'val02', 'val03'), ('val11', 'val12', 'val13')]). \
    toDF(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']). \
    withColumn('allcol_map', 
               func.map_from_entries(func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) for k in col_list]))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)
```

---

Based on the updated situation, you'd like to group by some key columns. Looking at the new expected output, you can use `concat_ws` and `collect_list` / `collect_set` to club the all / unique column values.

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('part0', 'val01', 'val02', 'val03'), ('part0', 'val11', 'val12', 'val13'), ('part1', 'val21', 'val22', 'val23')]). \
    toDF(['key_column', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']). \
    groupBy('key_column'). \
    agg(*[func.concat_ws(',', func.collect_set(k)).alias(k) for k in col_list]). \
    withColumn('allcol_map', 
               func.map_from_entries(func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) for k in col_list]))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |key_column|col1       |col2       |col3       |allcol_map                                                     |
# +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |part1     |val21      |val22      |val23      |{col1 -> val21, col2 -> val22, col3 -> val23}                  |
# |part0     |val01,val11|val02,val12|val03,val13|{col1 -> val01,val11, col2 -> val02,val12, col3 -> val03,val13}|
# +----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. Kindly let me know on how i can apply window partition along with this to partition the data. I am trying the below query, but its not working as expected. Partition_cols= [col_a, col_b, col_c]

Comment: @pradeepnadarajan the approach will be a bit different if you have to group by a column. do you want one map column value per partition?

Comment: @pradeepnadarajan can you share an expected sample output of how you intend the result to look like?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question accordingly. Can you please share your thoughts on how to partition the data accordingly.

Comment: @pradeepnadarajan added an update

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know where can i learn such scenarios for my project purpose.

Comment: there are a lot of good courses on coursera, datacamp, etc. @pradeepnadarajan

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if I can enrol for this course (link - https://www.coursera.org/projects/data-analysis-using-pyspark), or you can recommend me a better course which can cover such scenarios.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the above coursera content. Or you can suggest me something better as well. Thanks in advance. Much appreciated

Comment: @pradeepnadarajan that course seems too basic and you can enroll if you want an intro, but I'd suggest [this](https://www.coursera.org/projects/clean-explore-visualize-big-data-python-spark) and [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/pyspark-developer-course/) if you can

Answer (score 1):

```py
F.from_json(F.to_json(F.struct(df.columns)), 'map<string,string>')
```

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Value_N'),
     ('Value_a', 'Value_b', 'Value_M')],
    ['Column_1', 'Column_2', 'Column_N'])

df = df.select(F.from_json(F.to_json(F.struct(df.columns)), 'map<string,string>').alias('Map_output'))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |Map_output                                                     |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+
# |{Column_1 -> Value_1, Column_2 -> Value_2, Column_N -> Value_N}|
# |{Column_1 -> Value_a, Column_2 -> Value_b, Column_N -> Value_M}|
# +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```